# record level access in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions

I want want to restrict the records based on the user logged in viewing the records.

For example I have following two models:

```
Assignments
Users
```

So if a student (user) is viewing the summary of assignments he should be able to see only his assignments and able to perform view/delete/edit only his assignment.

But if a teacher (user) is viewing summary of assignments then he should see all assignments and can perform add/edit/delete on all assignments.

I am already aware I can do this by putting group conditions in find and then appropriate in code in view/edit/delete actions also.

My Question is  - what is the best ways to handle scenarios like this in cakephp? Putting conditions everywhere don't seems good way to me.

Comment: just move code on Model level. create apropriate method and use it. This allow to you write conditions only once and change all just revrite this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider as two separate problems to solve

### Access control

The first is how to deny students who e.g. just manipulate the url to attempt to view/edit/delete things they don't own. For that use isAuthorized, there's [an example in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what), adapted to the info in the question that'd be:

```
// app/Controller/AppController.php

public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    )
);

public function isAuthorized($user) {
    // Teachers can access/do everything - adapt to whatever identifies a teacher
    if ($user['is_teacher'])) {
        return true;
    }

    // Anyone logged in can access the index
    if ($this->action === 'index') { 
        return true;
    } 

    // The owner of a whatever can view, edit and delete it
    $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
    $owner = $this->{$this->modelClass}->field('user_id', array('id' => $id));
    if ($owner === $user['id'])) {
        return true;
    }

    // Default deny
    return false;
}
```

### Restrict student data

[The event system](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html), available since 2.1, is an easy way to enforce the data restriction mentioned. Again [there's a relevant example in the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#the-global-event-manager), adapted to the information in the question, that'd be:

```
// app/Controller/AssignmentsController.php

public function beforeFilter() {
    if (!$this->Auth->user('is_teacher')) {
        $currentUser = $this->Auth->user('id');
        $this->Assignment->getEventManager()->attach(
            function(CakeEvent $e) use ($currentUser) {
                $e->data[0]['conditions']['user_id'] = $currentUser;
                return $e->data[0];
            },
            'Model.beforeFind'
        );
    }
}
```

This will add a `user_id` condition to all finds, therefore the index listing will show only their own assignments, whereas for a teacher it will show all assignments.

Comment: that's a real helpful answers and detailed answer. +1 for isAuthorized use. I though something defines allowed actions role wise in configuration.

Comment: Just one thing, is there any perticular advantage of attaching even like this from controller rather then coding in the Model.beforeFind callback?

Comment: If you do it in beforeFind it is always applied (so all finds, always are checking the logged in user. 10 finds on User = 10 Auth calls to get the user id), but sure yes you can.  `AuthComponent::User` can be called statically.

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 separate models - StudentAssignments and  TeacherAssignments. both models can extend Assignments model. you can then filter your conditions in the beforeFind of each model.
This way, you have decoupled models and you can manipulate them appropriately.

Example:

```
App::uses('Assignment', 'Model');

class StudentAssignments extends Assignment
{
    function beforeFind( $queryData ) {
        $queryData['conditions'] = array_merge( (array)$queryData['conditions'], 
                                    array( $this->alias.'.user_id' => CakeSession::read('User.id') ) );
        return parent::beforeFind($queryData);
    }

}
```

Then you can call `$this->StudentAssignments->find('all');` to pull all assignments for a single user

Comment: That's helpfull @AyoAkinyemi I like the idea of separating model, May not be appropriate for all situations for but for some scenarios that can be super easy and decoupled.